# cannot modify java project in netbeans using maven

Tags: java, swing, maven, netbeans

Why I cannot modify my java maven project. It runs but when I modified the code the same old output is shown. I had searched but cant find the satisfactory answer.

Comment: Have you rebuilt (compiled) it?

Comment: run "mvn clean install"

Comment: Did you save your files? Did you ensure the files are saved to the disk?

Comment: Also, please do provide more details of your project, your maven etc. What happens when you call clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try:

1. "Clean and build" option
2. Remove /target/*jar and then
3. Shut down NetBeans ->remove
   /AppData/Local/NetBeans/Cache (in windows) -> run
   NetBeans agein

You can also try to combine them together if each alone won't work.

Comment: Correct answer, # 1 probably is enough. The `Clean and Build` command is demonstrated in the [NetBeans tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html).